# Fading image loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, weebly

I'm in the middle of making my Freelance portfolio, but I've run into a snag. I'm trying to make a fading slideshow of the HTML, CSS, and Javascript logos. My current jQuery code looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/UsiPtiWr). The first logo fades away fine, but then it stops. I've been looking at my code for a while now trying to figure out what's wrong. I don't know too much about how `window.setInterval()` works but a thought that crossed my mind was that after it goes through 1 if statement, it starts over and sets `shown` back to 0. Any help would be much appreciated. You can view my portfolio as it is now [here](http://jacobchearst.weebly.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, you need to put the variable outside the functions, this makes the variable global.

```
var shown = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
var slide = function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        // var shown = 0;
        shown += 1;
        if (shown === 1) {
            $('#html5').fadeOut(3000);
            $('#css3').fadeIn(3000);
        }
        if (shown === 2) {
            $('#css3').fadeOut(3000);
            $('#java-script').fadeIn(3000);
        }
        if (shown === 3) {
            $('#java-script').fadeOut(3000);
            $('#html5').fadeIn(3000);
            shown = 0; // this resets to 0 and makes you repeat all the animation
        }

        // This code will make a call inside a call of a functions (not recommended)
        // slide();
    }, 5000);
};
slide();
});
```

The set interval calls you're code every 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) so you don't need to call it again, you start the action with one call of the function "slide();".

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you should only call `window.setInterval` once. The way your code is structured, it's being called over and over again, which is probably not what you intended.

Here's an untested re-write that should get you on the right track.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var shown = 0;
    function slide() {
       if (shown === 0) {
           $('#html5').fadeOut(3000);
           $('#css3').fadeIn(3000);
      }
      if (shown === 1) {
          $('#css3').fadeOut(3000);
          $('#java-script').fadeIn(3000);
      }
      if (shown === 2) {
          $('#java-script').fadeOut(3000);
          $('#html5').fadeIn(3000);
      }
      shown = (shown+1)%3;
   }
   slide();
   window.setInterval( slide, 5000);
});
```